# Jquery Question - select and change background color of all hyperlinks save link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

need a quick help here. I have a series of hyperlinks all with the same class name. I want that when I click on anyone of the links - the background colors of all the other hyperlinks change except the link I have clicked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.className').click(function() {
    $('.className').not(this).css('backgroundColor', '#ccff00');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option here.

[Jquery Visited Plugin](http://remysharp.com/downloads/jquery.visited.js)

Define a CSS class "visited". And then..

```
$('#sidebar a').visited().addClass('visited');
```

Comment: He had got the answer earlier. Just thought to give a suggestion of an option.

Answer (score 2):

I would create another class that has the new background color and apply it to all except the one that was just clicked.

```
$('.first_class').click(function(){
  $('.first_class').not(this).addClass('new_class')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").onclick(function () {
  $(this).css("color");
});
```

With jQuery you can alter the CSS settings directly - so just build a function, choose a trigger (onclick, mouseover etc.) and you can alter the CSS settings...

Comment: This does not answer the question.